# Detect file size before to save it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, size

Is it possible to detect the size will be the file before saving it?

I have the file content which is a string, but i would like to check before how much space will take the file.

Any advice appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Buffer.byteLength(string)`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding).

Comment: cool one, will wait for more answers just to see different point of views, thanks a lot for now

Comment: @sbaaaang this is probably the most straight forward way if you don't have a buffer of the content already